# Trying to figure out ArcGIS API's `mapScale` variable and how it maps to OpenStreetMap's zoom level

Tags: arcgis-10.0, leaflet, scale, zoom, svg

I'm using ArcGIS' `/export` endpoint to get an `.svg` of a few map layers given a specific bounding box. However, when I apply the `.svg` as an image overlay to OpenStreetMap's world map using Leaflet, the overlay is scaled slightly too small.

I figured out that the `mapScale` parameter to the `/export` endpoint could be changed to alter the scale. However, there's no way for me to know what "scale value" my Leaflet map uses. As far as I can tell, Leaflet only knows about zoom levels and not "scale values".

Are there any resources for me to figure out how to find the proper scale value when exporting from ArcGIS?

Here's how I'm adding the `svg` layer:

```
var imglayer = 'layer.svg';
var imgbounds = [
    L.CRS.EPSG3857.unproject(L.point([-10791685.4014,4999593.1461])),
    L.CRS.EPSG3857.unproject(L.point([-8301672.7680,7822259.7266]))
];
L.imageOverlay(imglayer, imgbounds).addTo(mymap);
```

Comment: How do you include `.svg` in your map? That piece of code would help.

Comment: @TomazicM, added some code

Comment: This seems OK. Scale value is not importamt in this case, just coordinates of the bounding box. Since you have projected values, they shoud come from the same crs as your map. From your code it is 3857. This should be crs you are using in ArcGIS and in Leaflet.